# potential implications of the given conditions

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be a nondecreasing function defined on $[0,\infty]$. Given $x_1$ and $x_2$, suppose for any $\theta \in (0,1)$,
\begin{align*}
f(x_1) \geq \theta \cdot f\left(\frac{x_1}{\theta}\right)+(1-\theta) \cdot f\left(0\right)\\
f(x_2) \geq \theta \cdot f\left(\frac{x_2}{\theta}\right)+(1-\theta) \cdot f\left(0\right)
\end{align*}
Is it true that
$$
f(\theta \cdot x_1+(1-\theta) \cdot x_2) \geq \theta \cdot f(x_1)+(1-\theta) \cdot f(x_2), \quad \forall \theta \in (0,1)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the two conditions given are true, and assume by contradiction that the function is strictly convex. Then
$$f(\theta y_1+ (1-\theta)y_2)<\theta f(y_1)+(1-\theta)f(y_2)$$
for any $y_1, y_2 \geq 0$, such that $y_1\neq y_2$, and for all $ \theta \in (0,1)$. Then, for $y_1=x_1/\theta$, $y_2=0$, we have that
$$f(x_1)<\theta f(x_1/\theta)+(1-\theta)f(0)$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! Since $\theta \in (0,1)$, it seems that $x^2<x^2/\theta$, right?

Comment: @ cxxu96 , I now believe either one of the two conditions given is sufficient. Also, I can't show that the monotonicity  is necessary neither for the given conditions to make sense,  nor for the proof.  Please, review the proof and clarify two two points.